# Incrementing the reference count on an object created by a constructor exposed to boost::python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm exposing a C++ object meant to be subclassed in Python. When constructed these objects are referenced by some container C++ side. (actually std::map) One object can only be destructed after being explicitely removed from this container. However they are managed by Python and thus destroyed when there are no Python reference left to it but still remain referenced by the container.

I have to tell Python that when I constructed the object I kept a reference to it. I can't find any simple way to do that. I didn't find any calling policy that mean "increment the reference count to the returned object by one". Should I implement my own calling policy to do that ? (I have no idea how to implement a calling policy) Or is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Who places the objects in the container?

Comment: The C++ constructor which ignores it have been called by Python.

Comment: I realise that what i said was ambiguous. The container i'm talking about only contains references, not the objects themselves. It  actually is a std::map of pointers.

Comment: Why not just have the destructor remove the object from the container?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The containers is intended to keep references to objects. This way, I can retrieve them later. They have to be explicitely removed from the container to be destroyed, not the other way round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a special policy which increases the reference count to the object being constructed.

```
template <class Base = default_call_policies>
struct incref_return_value_policy : Base
{
    static PyObject *postcall(PyObject *args, PyObject *result)
    {
        PyObject *self = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0);
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return result;
    }
};
```

It can then be used as any other policy :

```
class_<A>("A", init<>()[ incref_return_value_policy<>() ] );
```

Comment: This works for me.  However, I am at a loss as to how the memory gets cleaned up.  My 'A' class destructor is called, which surprised me a bit.  I figured since I incremented the python reference, but never decremented, it, that I would leak the object.  Do you know how the dereference is done?

Comment: If you didn't decrement the reference count and the object get destroyed before Py_Finalize is called, it's likely there is a bug somewhere. Maybe, your objects are destroyed during Py_Finalize.

Comment: It is before Py_Finalize.  I have a python loop calling a function over and over that creates an 'A' object.  I'm printing at the top of the function and also in A's destructor.  A is destructed between loop iterations.  What sort of bug would cause the dereference?

Comment: Is your policy applied ? Do you discard any reference in Python code ? If you didn't write any Py_DECREF yourself, i don't see what would cause it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little example that does what I think you want.  The whole procedure centers around using a "holder" class that tells Boost.Python to actually use a different class when constructing instances of a certain type in Python, and that it should pass the Python object as the first argument to any constructors of the custom wrapper class.  You can find more info here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html

(see the "HeldType semantics" discussion in particular).

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

namespace bp = boost::python;

class Base {
public:
    virtual double go(int x) const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class PyBase : public Base {
public:
    explicit PyBase(PyObject* self) : _self(self) {
        Py_INCREF(_self); // THIS LEAKS MEMORY IF THERE'S NO DECREF!
    }
    virtual double go(int x) const {
        return bp::call_method<double>(_self, "go", x);
    }
private:
    PyObject * _self;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    bp::class_<Base,PyBase,boost::noncopyable>(
        "Base",
        bp::init<>() // the PyObject* arg is implicit
    ) 
        .def("go", &PyBase::go)
        ;
}
```

But there are some caveats:

- If you don't implement `go` in the Python that inherits from `Base`, you'll get an unhelpful Python exception message about infinite recursion.  I'm also not sure how to make the virtual function fall back to C++ if there is a default implementation (you could probably figure it out by looking at the code for `bp::wrapper`, which does very similar things).
- If you return a `Base` object from a C++ function by reference or pointer, you won't have a Python object that contains a `PyBase` object unless the instance you returned actually was a PyBase object to begin with (that makes sense if you think about it, of course).
- If you want to return by value, you need to add a copy constructor that takes a `PyObject*` as its first argument before you can remove the `boost::noncopyable` template argument from the `bp::class_` call.
- The `Py_INCREF` statement in the constructor tells Python that "your code" is taking an extra reference to this object.  But it's not clear to me how you want to add the corresponding `Py_DECREF`: if all you have is a `std::map` of `Base*` objects, there's no way to get a `PyObject*` from that later.
- One way around the above problem would be to have a container of `bp::handle<>` or `bp::object`, and construct one of those from `self` to put in the container.  But in that case, you need to make sure those containers are emptied before your program ends, because you'll get segmentation faults if a Python destructor is called at static destructor time.

Comment: I didn't achieve to use your solution when using boost::python::wrapper which is the typical way to handle virtual call to python derived classes. Is this why you used this way to call virtual methods ?

Comment: Yes.  The boost::python::wrapper method is simpler and more automatic.  It actually uses a very similar approach in its implementation, but it does not give you access to the `PyObject*` you need in this case (because it's a private data member of the wrapper).  Everything you can do with boost::python::wrapper can be done this way as well, but you have to write more code to handle things like C++ default implementations of virtual functions.

Comment: In order to keep the utility provided by the wrapper class from boost::python, i prefer to let reference count handling in the policies. For your fourth point, boost::python is able to retrieve the PyObject* when perforing to_python conversion. But it's not even needed. When python call the function that will remove the object from the std::map then another call policy will decrement the refcounter : the policy have direct access to PyObjects.

Comment: Yup, I think your call policy solution is cleaner than mine, and many of the concerns I had about how to DECREF go away if you are also wrapping the only functions that can remove things from the container.